# Selecting nodes depending on sibling node criteria using XSLT

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have XML like this:

```
<child_metadata>
    <metadata>
        <attributes>
                <metadata_key value="include"/>
                <metadata_value value="value1"/>
        </attributes>
    </metadata>
    <metadata>
        <attributes>
                <metadata_key value="dont_include"/>
                <metadata_value value="value2"/>
        </attributes>
    </metadata>
    <metadata>
        <attributes>
                <metadata_key value="include"/>
                <metadata_value value="value3"/>
        </attributes>
    </metadata>
</child_metadata>
```

Using XSLT (without any extensions), I want to select only those values for which the metadata_key is "include".  So, for this example, I want to select value1 and value3.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath expression to use (for a template or in a for-each loop) would be:

```
//metadata_value[../metadata_key/@value='include']/@value
```

Since it isn't clear what you mean by "select" I cannot post a complete XSLT sample. XSLT is for transformation, not query ("selection" of data); the query is done with XPath expressions such as the one I provided you above.

Answer (score 2):

For the `metadata_value` node set, use

```
//metadata/attributes[metadata_key/@value='include']/metadata_value
```

add `@value` to get the values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
//atributes[metadata_key/@value='include']/metadata_vale/@value
```

or (as Lucero post)

```
//metadata_value[../metadata_key/@value='include']/@value
```

But, depending on what you want to do, you should use keys because here is a cross-reference (`metadata_key/@value` is used as the key to `metadata_value/@value`). It is also good to avoid the descendant axis.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/child_metadata/metadata/attributes[metadata_key/@value='include']/metadata_value/@value
```

Using the `//` abbreviation often has poor efficiency as this causes the whole (sub) tree to be traversed.